# insert input time content in mysql type time

Tags: php, mysql, time

this is my table in html php, i get the names of employees from DB

[image]

i need to insert in the database the content of input type=time

this is my php code

```
<?php
$nom='';
$prénom='';
$output='';
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ntr-ktb123", "absence");  
$sql="SELECT * FROM employés;";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
echo "<table>
    <tr>
<th>nom</th>
<th>prénom</th>
<th>Entrée matin</th>
<th>Sortie matin</th>
<th>Entrée soir</th>
<th>Sortie soir</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
   echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['NomEmp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PrénomEmp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='time' " . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='time' " . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='time' " . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='time' " . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";  
  }  
  $output="</table>";
  echo $output;  
?>
```

i have no idea how to insert the content of input type='time' in mysql DB 
neither with type varchar or time.

can someone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your table schema and your insert code.

Comment: Where's your insert statement? Also, why are all the input-tags not closed and missing a bunch of attributes (like `name` etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of your field in your database. Assuming it's a DATETIME, you could format it with a date().

`echo "<td>" . "<input type='time' value='" . date("H:i", strtotime($row['entree_matin'])) . "' /></td>";`

Answer (score 0):

insert your time inside the  'value' parameter in the time tag

exemple :''

```html
<input id="time" type="time" value="12:13">
```

but first you have to insert the right format :  hh:mm